# How can I get browser to prompt to save password ajax + jquery form submit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, authentication, safari

I have **three** input filed in Login form.

I CAN'T get **Safari** to prompt me to save the password for the Login page but that work in IE, FireFox and Chrome

Form

```
    <form class="form" method="post" action="#">
        <label>Email :</label>
        <input type="text" name="demail" id="email">
        <label>rrrr :</label>
        <input type="text" name="demail2" id="email2">
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
    </form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'login.php',
                data: {
                    email: $("#email").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data === 'Correct') {
//                        window.location.replace('admin/admin.php');
                        window.location="https://www.google.com";
                    }
                    else {
                       window.location="https://www.google.com";
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

I should keep three input fields for login page. how can i get save password in safari with three input fields?

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: Would it help if you changed your submit button to type 'button' like this: <input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login"> I mean do you need to submit the data, after all you got your $ajax doing the same job (if I understood correctly)